# Why this avr/io.h header give me fatal error?

Tags: c, avr-gcc

I add this header on my C program. And it gives me no such file or directory.
Here is that error: fatal error: avr/io.h: No such file or directory.

Here is all of my code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>

int main(void)
{
  DDRB |= (1 << PB5);  // Set PB5 as output

  while (1)
  {
    PORTB |= (1 << PB5);  // Turn on LED
    _delay_ms(1000);  // Wait for 1 second
    PORTB &= ~(1 << PB5);  // Turn off LED
    _delay_ms(1000);  // Wait for 1 second
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The file you tried to include does not exist. Why that is, we have no idea. What makes you think it *should* exist in that path?

Comment: @nvoigt I installed codeblocks properly. And some file that I am trying the include gives me that errror .

Comment: There seems to be entensive setup required to use the AVR toolchain with Code:Blocks. Did you do that?

Comment: No, I didnt. Can you help me ?

Comment: Did yo also install avr-gcc properly (and AVR-LibC too for that matter)?

Comment: Check the output of `avr-gcc -v foo.c`.  Amongst other stuff, it prints `#include <...> search starts here:` followed by several paths.  If `avr/io.h` is not found in any of these paths, your installation is broken.  Moreover, C::B is known to set options by default which don't apply for avr-gcc, so make sure that C::B won't pass rubbish options to avr-gcc.

Comment: I didn't install avr-gcc. When I install, what should I do ?

Comment: So you are compiling a program that's supposed to run on an AVR with a toolchain that won't produce code for AVR? Which compiler are you using then? Plain `gcc` will generate code for your host machine like Intel `x86_64`, and such toolchain does not have anything like `avr/io.h`.  So install avr-gcc Toolchain.